# API changes and users upgrading your app

Tags: android, ios

I'm trying to help my company develop a strategy on when we should require customers to upgrade their installed mobile app prior to interacting with our back end services.

Right now, our apps have been on the market for 20 months and we've done numerous revisions to the app and the backend services. Only one of those has 'broken' anything so that customers using older versions of the app were no longer able to use the app without upgrading to a new version. We have apps for iOS, Android and Kindle Fire, all of which use the same backend services. We currently have the ability to require customers to upgrade, we're just not using it.

So the two questions:
1) Do you require users to upgrade, and if so
2) How many older versions of the app do you support.

(Additional info, this is an eCommerce app, so if you could say what type of app you're using as well, that would be helpful.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look at a strategy of versioning your APIs. So that users with older/un-upgraded apps would have problems. And when they upgrade to your new builds, they would switch to the new API version and everything would work.

Coming to how many versions you support. That really depends on you. If you want to force the users to update, then make your servers deny requests to the old APIs. That way, if the user is interested to use the app further, he has to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that the app and the API are both versioned. We do know what app version works with which API version. We always have the new API version in production prior to releasing the new app version to work with it.

Comment: We have the mechanism to require an upgrade, but we've never used it. I was looking for more suggestions on when its appropriate to use it and how long other people left old versions out in the wild before they required an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

E*Commerce app. We control the endpoint the app connects to. In every upstream HTTP header, the app puts its version number. The web and optionally add a tag in the downstream header of "yellow", "red", "disable".

If the app gets a yellow key, it tells the user at some good point "This app is out of date - you should update to the latest version soon"

if the app sees a red key, it tells the user to update soon or the app will stop working.

If the disable header is seen. the app stops sending upstream messages and tells the user that the app no longer works, if they would like to continue using the service then update the app.